# Como integrar webservice com website imobiliário?

Tags: php, xml, web-service, soap

Eu sou programador mas não cheguei a fazer a parte de lógica de programação e estou com dificuldade num determinado assunto. Eu preciso integrar informações imobiliárias em um website através de dados contidos em uma web-service. O manual de integração é **[este](http://www.vistasoft.com.br/download/RQV_015-WebService%20de%20integra%C3%A7%C3%A3o%20dos%20im%C3%B3veis%20ver2_rev01.pdf)** e eu preciso entender o que o manual está sugerindo que eu faça.

A primeira coisa que eu pensei em fazer foi buscar as informações via PHP para poder usá-las como fonte de dados e alimentar o meu site. Mas ai comecei a ler algumas coisas relacionadas a SOAP que para mim é nada mais que o protocolo de autenticação do web-service, me corrijam se estiver errado.

Comecei a ler algumas coisas também sobre XML e pensei ... será que o sistema quer que eu gere um arquivo `xml` ou `soap` para posteriormente consultá-lo com PHP? Mas será que este **[trabalho](http://axitech.com.br/vista/index.php)** em PHP já não é suficiente para eu executar minhas tarefas?

Podem me ajudar a esclarecer o que eu realmente preciso para começar o meu projeto, eu faço tudo na raça, sei que é mais difícil mas prometo que vou começar a manter uma rotina de estudos.

**Resumindo:**

- *O PHP que eu criei já é suficiente pra fazer minhas consultas?*
  **Percebi** que o PHP que criei conforme mostrado nesse [link](http://pastebin.com/nNcnkzkL) já é a requisição com o método de autenticação via SOAP, ou seja, ele já está retornando tudo que está no web-service.
- *Preciso criar arquivos XML ou SOAP?*
  **Percebi** que a consulta já está sendo enviada através desse [arquivo](http://pastebin.com/nNcnkzkL) contendo seus parâmetros, ele mesmo que recebe o resultado da requisição.
- *Porque deveria criar estes arquivos?*
  **Percebi** que não existe a necessidade de se criar nenhum arquivo adicional para receber o resultado da consulta, este resultado está sendo recebido [aqui](http://axitech.com.br/vista/index.php).

O **web-service** requisitado retornou 950 registros com 175 campos cada registro em 10 segundos. É um bom tempo?

Comment: Eu acho que a pergunta é "ampla demais". Quem quiser responder precisar ler um manual? (Por favor, link real, shortened não é legal). Analisar uma array de 16 mil linhas? . . . Tenho a impressão que suas 3 perguntas podiam ser distribuidas em outras 9...

Comment: Desculpa o **shortened** era porque o link era muito grande. Ainda estou aprendendo a usar o SOpt e estou muito entusiasmado com o portal. Quanto a pergunta, o usuário que me respondeu resumiu 80% do que eu preciso saber, então essa pergunta só parece grande mas se resume em explicação resumida dos acontecimentos lógicos. Peço que reavalie o -1. Obrigado.

Comment: @MarcosViniciusNasc.Pereira A resposta diz genericamente algo sobre *webservices*. No meu entendimento não responde o que você perguntou então a pergunta talvez não esteja clara. Você pode decidir o que é bom para você mas será estranho você passar tantas informações e uma resposta tão genérica resolver o seu problema. Além disto, se tem código ou outras informações , coloque na pergunta, provavelmente ela ficaria mais específica.

Comment: Tecnicamente, não foi -1, foi um *voto pra fechar* que acabo de retirar, já que parece que talvez não vi a floresta, só as árvores, e deixo pra outros decidirem. . . . Mas seu feedback na resposta indica que é melhor vc ir abrindo novas perguntas enquanto avança no seu projeto. Como dizem lá nos english: *just my 2 cents* ;)

Comment: Esta pergunta parece ser descontextualizada porque é sobre um problema diferente do que foi perguntado, e não tem como ser aproveitada por futuros visitantes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tentarei explicar de uma forma didática. Mas detalhes você precisará pesquisar os termos e padrões.

Quando consumidos dados em WebServices deste tipo (no documento que apresentou) você precisa com o seu PHP formular uma pergunta de forma a fazer o servidor do WS entender o que você quer e te responder corretamente. Basicamente o que está no manual é a especificação de como se fazer a pergunta ao webservice.

Você construirá um arquivo XML contendo os parâmetros da sua pergunta, padronizados da forma que o servidor exige. Quando você enviar este arquivo XML para ele usando o PHP com o SOAP, o WS irá validar o documento que você enviou e fornecerá a resposta que você precisa, ele te retornará outro XML com os dados solicitados ou um erro de requisição se for o caso.

Comment: Este link http://pastebin.com/nNcnkzkL mostra o código que faz a requisição ao web-service via SOAP, então cheguei a conclusão de que o arquivo de requisição já está sendo gerado automaticamente, certo? E este link http://axitech.com.br/vista/index.php é a resposta. Então a única coisa que me falta fazer é consultar este arquivo, certo?